# UWP: Add styling to specific words in textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a couple of strings in a resource file, which all needs to be translated. These strings will be concatenated into one sentence and displayed inside a `TextBlock` in my app and I would like to make some of the strings bold inside the `TextBlock`.
E.g.

```
string a = "This {0} a {1} string.";
string b = "is";
string c = "formatted";
string output = string.Format(a, b, c);
```

And I would like the output to be: This **is** a **formatted** string.

Any hints and tips are welcome.

Comment: can you provide more information ?

Comment: Try using `<Run />` inside your text block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<Run />` inside your `TextBlock` for additional styling on specific words.

```
<TextBlock>
    This
    <Run FontWeight="Bold">is</Run>
    a
    <Run FontWeight="Bold">formatted</Run>
    string.
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

---

### Update

Here's a simple example to give you an idea. I have created a `UserControl` called `TextControl` where the XAML contains only this -

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" />
```

In its code-behind, I have defined three dependency properties. One is to take the full resource string, the other two are for passing in `{0}` and `{1}`. The idea is to split the full string by *space*, then replace `{x}` with the input properties and also make them bold.

```
public string ResourceString
{
    get => (string)GetValue(ResourceStringProperty);
    set => SetValue(ResourceStringProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ResourceString", typeof(string), typeof(TextControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), (s, e) =>
    {
        var self = (TextControl)s;
        var full = e.NewValue.ToString();

        foreach (var seg in full.Split(' '))
        {
            var run = new Run();

            if (seg.Contains("{0}"))
            {
                run.Text = self.Input0;
                run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            }
            else if (seg.Contains("{1}"))
            {
                run.Text = self.Input1;
                run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            }
            else
            {
                run.Text = seg;
            }

            run.Text += " ";

            self.MyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }
    }));

public string Input0
{
    get => (string)GetValue(Input0Property);
    set => SetValue(Input0Property, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty Input0Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Input0", typeof(string), typeof(TextControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string Input1
{
    get => (string)GetValue(Input1Property);
    set => SetValue(Input1Property, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty Input1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Input1", typeof(string), typeof(TextControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
```

Then you can just use it like this -

```
<local:TextControl Input0="is" Input1="formatted" ResourceString="This {0} indeed a {1} string." />
```

And you get -

[image]

Comment: Note if you *only* need to make some text bold without changing anything else, you can replace Run with Bold too.

Comment: Since the strings come from resource files and I cannot be sure of the order of the strings at runtime so I cannot specify them in xaml directly like this unfortunately, e.g. string "a" could look like this "{0} bla bla {1} bla bla"

Comment: I managed to get it working by myself a couple of minutes after this post by parsing the string in code behind and putting it together without the use of string.Format(). Big thanks for the help and reply!

Comment: @MagnusGunnarsson if you think it helped, please consider accepting it as the answer. Also, keeps in mind it's always easier if you could wrap your logic within a control like my answer above. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a lot of information about styling a textblock: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/

I recommended using the span approach for your problem since you want to work in program code

Good Luck